# Nhibernate cache provider that uses System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: nhibernate, caching

Is there any implementation of Nhibernate's cache provider that uses the memorycache class of system.runtim.caching?

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, but it would be a really welcome patch if you want to create it.

You can browse the existing implementations at http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Caches/

You can submit your patch to http://jira.nhforge.org

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an implementation is now in NHibernate-Caches on GitHub:
https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate-Caches/tree/master/RtMemoryCache